# Could not load file or assembly when deployed to Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have a nuget package for logging installed In my API, and when I run the API locally, everything works.

However, when I deploy my API to a Azure App Service, I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore,
> Version=2.17.0.146, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.

The mentioned package that can't be found are used In my nuget package.

So why does work locally, and not In Azure?

Any suggestions what I can do to solve this?

Comment: What method do you use to deploy? Can you find that dll if you browse the folders with [the kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)?

Comment: @Crowcoder: I can see that the dll for the nuget package is there, INT.InformationServices.Common.Insights.dll, but I can't see the dll's that belongs to the nuget package.

Comment: Yes, any Nuget references will be placed in the bin folder. (technically nuget packages can do things other than pull in dlls, but what you are talking about is a dll)

Comment: @Crowcoder: I can find the dll of my nuget-package, INT.InformationServices.Common.Insights.dll

Comment: Oh, it sounds like you did not include a dependency reference in your nuspec file for the App Insights nuget package.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Okey, so how do I do that? Any documentation of this that you can refer to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element

Comment: @Crowcoder: So I must have nuspec file in the project for my nuget-package?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234367/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-bryan).